# Python Deep Learning Yolo v8 slow fps in real time

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I had been recently training a yolo v8 nano model with 1.5k images with the size of 640x640 and I decided to make it live with this code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
from ultralytics.yolo.v8.detect.predict import DetectionPredictor
import cv2
model = YOLO("Model/best.pt")
model.predict(source="0", show=True, conf=0.4)
```

the model is able to predict the objects accurately, but the problem is that it is very slow barely achieves 2 fps. I have to hold it for a long time.

My pc specs are:
i9-13950H 24 cores and 5.6 hz
32 gigs of ram
windows 11 home

also I do not have cuda support for the model detection but my cpu and ram are barely used. Is there a way to use CPU but still achive at least 30-60 fps.

**Please drop comments and ideas you are welcomed!**

I tried it with opencv and took each frame stored it as an image it was way slower please help!

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/3853#issuecomment-1644880061

Answer (score 0):

convert the model to onnx formate using this code:

jupyter notebook:

! yolo export model=path_to_model.pt format=onnx

terminal:

yolo export model=path_to_model.pt format=onnx

you will have another model in the same file as the original model but with .onnx